# Jstl error (array display)

Tags: jstl

I'm following a video about web development jee. The programmer used the "jstl" library to do the array display (img1)[the image from the video](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t8bj1.png)

But i get this one if i run my application ! (img 2)
[my page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QL2lG.png)

code:

```
            <c:forEach items="${model.produits}" var="p">
                <tr>
                    <td>${p.reference}</td>
                    <td>${p.designation}</td>
                    <td>${p.prix}</td>
                    <td>${p.quantite}</td>   
                </tr>
            </c:forEach> 
        </table>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

The EL (Expression Language) is set to be ignored in your deployment descriptor or JSP.

You can look:

- In the JSP for `<%@ page isELIgnored="true" %>` and/or
- In the deployment descriptor `web.xml` for `<el-ignored>true</el-ignored>`

If you find this. Turn it to `false`.

**[The Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19316-01/819-3669/bnajh/index.html) say:**

> Each JSP page has a default mode for EL expression evaluation. The
>   default value varies depending on the version of the web application
>   deployment descriptor. The default mode for JSP pages delivered with a
>   Servlet 2.4 descriptor is to evaluate EL expressions; this
>   automatically provides the default that most applications want. The
>   default mode for JSP pages delivered using a descriptor from Servlet
>   2.3 or before is to ignore EL expressions; this provides backward compatibility.

So can check at the top of `web.xml`, if you can find `web-app_2_3.xsd` or less, you have to add this in the deployment descriptor:

```
<jsp-config>
  <jsp-property-group>
      <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
      <el-ignored>false</el-ignored>
   </jsp-property-group>
</jsp-config>
```

Comment: Thank you friend :) :) :) I add this line : <%@ page isELIgnored="false" %> in the jsp page it run correctly !

Comment: I am glad, i could help. You can accept and upvote an answer, by clicking on the checkmark and arrow-top on the left side.